# OpenVPN user nobody permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, openvpn

My OpenVPN server is running under `nobody` account and it is configured to call a script once a client gets connected (for logging client's IP along with some info):

```
client-connect "/etc/openvpn/scripts/clientconnect.sh 443"
```

The problem is that script can successfully write into `/etc/openvpn/logs/` but it fails to write into `/var/log/openvpn/`
Permissions are identical for both destinations:

```
root@vpn:/etc/openvpn# ll /var/log/openvpn/client-connect.log
-rw-r--rw- 1 root root 1 Apr 19 19:10 /var/log/openvpn/client-connect.log
root@vpn:/etc/openvpn# ll /etc/openvpn/logs/client-connect.log
-rw-r--rw- 1 root root 63103291 Apr 19 19:20 /etc/openvpn/logs/client-connect.log
```

Output of ls -ld / /var /var/log /var/log/openvpn/:

```
root@vpn:~# ls -ld / /var /var/log /var/log/openvpn/
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root   4096 Apr 13 20:15 /
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root   4096 Feb  6  2016 /var
drwxrwxr-x 14 root syslog 4096 Apr 19 00:00 /var/log
drw-rw-rw-  3 root root   4096 Apr 19 19:19 /var/log/openvpn/
```

I get the following error for `/var/log/openvpn/` destination:

```
/etc/openvpn/scripts/clientconnect.sh: 12: cannot create /var/log/openvpn/client-connect.log: Permission denied
```

Can't figure out, what can prevent OpenVPN from writing into /var/log/openvpn/client-connect.log?

(I know that OpenVPN could be run under some other login, but I'd like to deal with permissions issue)

Comment: `ls -ld / /var /var/log /var/log/openvpn/` added to your question, please. You'll see that the `openvpn` directory is not accessible by the `nobody` account. And the point of the `nobody` account is that nothing (nobody) should be using it. It is not an anonymous account. It is an account that no process should use. Create your own not-a-person account to run OpenVPN if you need, but don't use `nobody`

Comment: `ls -ld` output added. I know, it is recommended to use dedicated account for each service, but `noboby` is currently used only for OpenVPN, and also I'd like to understand why exactly access is denied.

Comment: It's also used for ssh security isolation, with the expectation that no process runs as `nobody`. I suppose if you want to provide a potential back door into ssh by running a process that handles external connections from the internet that's your choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directory permissions for `/var/log/openvpn` itself are wrong. You *must* provide execute (search) permission for a user, group, or everyone else if you want them to be able to access items in that directory